# .csx Files: Combine all using statements and #r into one file

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, csx

I have .csx files that has a lot of using statements and #r statements, but each of these files have the same using and #r statements. Is there a way to abstract this? Like having a file `reference.csx` or some other file extensions that can be used so that instead of having a multiple lines of using and #r statements, it is just 1 (or even better, a way to make it 0).